# Strtotime and PHP - formatting a PDO query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I've been learning the basics of using PDO with PHP, and my query worked.
This is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>



<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "test";

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=goodsdb", $username, $password);

    //echo "Connected to database"; // check for connection

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

    $sql = "Select * from items";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        //echo $row["goods"]. "<br />";
    }

    $db = null; // close the database connection

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<p>
<?php
echo $row["goods"];
?>
</p>
<p>
<?php
echo $row["auctiondate"];
?>
</p>
</div>
<?php require 'footer.php' ?>
```

It worked, no errors so far. Notice that I have commented out the echo part after the foreach, and echo'ed the rows using the php  delimiters - is this good practise, or should I uncomment it?

However, how do I get the auctiondate field in my database to display data as:

6th April 2013, 12:00pm

rather than

2013-06-06 12:00:00 (it is stored as DATETIME in the database)

I am not sure whether to use date or strtotime to display this and would like help on getting the date to format properly.

This project is a simple website to display data from a database for a warehouse in PDO/MySQL - a simple testing site, basically.

I am using PHP 5.4.4, and am using MAMP, on OS X 10.8.3 Mountain Lion, if this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$mydate = date("jS M Y, g:ia", strtotime($datefrommysql));
```

For date-formatting, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 3):

Either use the date format functionality in php or use the mysql date_format function like this:

```
Select *,date_format(auctiondate,'%D %M %Y, %h:%i%p' ) as 'mod_date' from items
```

This will return exactly `6th April 2013, 12:00pm` in the field `mod_date`

Answer (score 1):

As your question for some reason tagged with PDO (which has nothing to do with date formats), I'd make some improvements in the way you are using PDO

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "test";

$opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=goodsdb", $username, $password, $opt);

$sql = "Select * from items";
$result = $db->query($sql);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    //echo $row["goods"]. "<br />";
}
```

it would be the right way of handling PDO errors